# 3 uniform points on a circle

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, independence, uniform-distribution

> Suppose 3 (distinct) points are uniformly and independently distributed on a circle of unit length (smaller than a unit circle!). This is really circle and not disc. Call one of these points $B$. Let $E$ be the random variable denoting the distance (along the circle) of the point $B$ to its anti-clockwise neighbour. Find the pdf of $E$.

There's an argument that goes:

1. Call these 3 points $A,B,C$ s.t. they are iid $\sim \ Unif(0,1)$ (or $[0,1)$ or whatever).
2. The pdf of $E$ is $f_E(e)=2(1-e) 1_{(0,1)}(e)$ (the pdf of a minimum of 2 iid Unif(0,1) or of the absolute value difference of 2 iid Unif(0,1)). This can be seen as like 2 ways to choose the anti-clockwise neighbour and then '$1-e$ ways' to choose the position of the clockwise neighbour.

**My concerns**: Since we're not dealing with discrete, I find this '$1-e$ ways' to be very heuristic. I don't even see where exactly we use independence or uniformity. I'm hoping for something more rigorous like a precise formula relating $E$ to to $A,B,C$. (However, I think this makes perfect rigorous sense in the discrete case like 10 points on a circle separated $\frac1{10}$ each and then $A,B,C$ are discrete uniform.)

**Question**: How do we make this argument precise? I mean, what is $E$ exactly in relation to $A,B,C$?

Comment: @fblundun thanks! circumference = 1 and your assumption is correct. just realised you can infer from the post, but you'd have to read more into it instead of original problem. edited. anyway $E$ is based on other random variables which are based on $A,B,C$?

Comment: I deleted my original comment because I noticed there was a 3rd possible interpretation that I hadn't considered: that the "distance" to be calculated is the minimum distance along the circumference, but it could be clockwise or anticlockwise. e.g. if $B$ is at 0 degrees and the other 2 points are at 270 degrees, then under this interpretation the distance would only be 0.25 rather than 0.75. But sounds like my original interpretation was actually the right one. Guess the precise formula would be something like `E = min(arg(A) - arg(B), arg(C) - arg(B)) / (2 pi)`.

Comment: @fblundun ah thanks. What's wrong with $E=\min\{A-B,C-B\}$ ? possible negatives? but like $\arg$ is to get the angle right? if so then i think there could still be negatives there

Comment: ah I see what you mean. I guess to avoid negatives I should have wrapped the whole thing in a "[modulo 1](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18131)" so that e.g. -0.25 would be transformed to +0.75.

Comment: $E=\min\{(A-B) \bmod 1, (C-B) \bmod 1)\}$ ? @fblundun

Comment: @fblundun btw mod 1 means (in this particular situation) +1 if negative and +0 if positive?

Comment: I agree with your last 2 comments.

Comment: @fblundun thanks! post as answer?

Comment: @fblundun one concern though: i think i can show $X:=(A-B) \bmod 1$ and $Y:=(C-B) \bmod 1$ are identically Unif(0,1), but are they independent? sounds like i'd have to compute the joint distribution and then thereby show independence, but i'm wondering if there's another way to show this independence. it looks like $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent on $B$. would this help?

Comment: Yes I think that's the right idea - conditional on any specific value of $B$, both $X$ and $Y$ are independently uniformly distributed.

Comment: @fblundun and then can upgrade to full independence?

Comment: How is the distance $E$ computed? Is it Euclidean distance? Or just the difference in counterclockwise angle?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus 'denoting the distance (along the circle)' ? so i guess angle and then convert to arc length

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I missed this part 'along' while reading.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus oh ok i thought i was still unclear. i know i was unclear initially like before fblundun 1st commented

Answer (score 3):

*I am going to generalise your problem to allow any number of points.  The problem is just as easy to solve with this generalisation.*

Since you are measuring from a pre-specified point, and since all points are uniform, without loss of the structure of the problem we can set the reference point at $0$.  This can easily be achieved by rotating the circle so that the reference point is at the top after the points are distributed; see additional information in the section below.

Now suppose you have $n \in \mathbb{N}$ other points, which I will label as $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID U}[0,1]$, where the measure of distance is taken in an anti-clockwise direction.  (In your exposition of the problem you have called the other points $A$ and $C$, but I will generalise from this.)  The anti-clockwise distance from the reference point to the first neighbour is:

$$E \equiv \min(X_1,...,X_n).$$

For all $0 \leqslant e \leqslant 1$ the cumulative distribution function for this distance is:

$$\begin{align}
F_E(e)
\equiv \mathbb{P}(E \leqslant e)
&= 1 - \mathbb{P}(E > e) \\[12pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(X_i > e) \\[6pt]
&= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n (1-e) \\[12pt]
&= 1 - (1-e)^n, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

so the density function for this distance is:

$$\begin{align}
f_E(e) = \frac{dF_E}{de}(e) 
&= n (1-e)^{n-1} \cdot \mathbb{I}(0 \leqslant e \leqslant 1) \\[12pt]
&= \text{Beta}(e | 1, n). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

This shows that we have $E \sim \text{Beta}(1, n)$ in the general problem.  Your problem has three points, so you have $n=2$ points that are not the reference point, which gives the density you stated in your question.

---

**More information on the transformation:** Suppose we let $Y_0, Y_1, ..., Y_n \sim \text{IID U}[0,1]$ be points uniformly distributed on the circle prior to re-framing (taken as anti-clockwise distances around the circle).  Taking $Y_0$ as the reference point (which you have labelled as $B$) we can define the anti-clockwise distances from the reference point as:

$$X_i \equiv (Y_i - Y_0) \text{ mod } 1.$$

By definition we have $X_0 = 0$, which means that using the values $X_0,X_1,...,X_n$ re-frames the analysis to set the reference point at zero.  It is simple to show that $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID}[0,1]$, so re-framing to put the reference point at zero does not change the underlying distributional framework of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ben. 1 - Wait so this is really a matter of a simple answer $E=\min\{A,C\}$, and so the hard work is not really computing the pdf of $E$ but explaining why we just do away with $B$ (the reference point thing you said) ?

Comment: 2 - If the 3 points are $A,B,C$, then I think like let $X$ be anti-clockwise distance from $B$ to $A$ and $Y$ be anti-clockwise distance from $B$ to $C$. Then $E=\min\{X,Y\}$. This way your $(X_1,X_2)$ = my $(X,Y)$ instead of my $(A,C)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: 3 - are you using any notion of conditional independence here?

Comment: I added a section re-framing the problem to rotate the circle to put the reference point at zero.  In your notation you would have $E = \min ( (A-B) \text{ mod } 1, (C-B) \text{ mod } 1)$, where both quantities in this minimum are IID uniform values.

Comment: Thanks Ben. 4 - About 'simple to show that', are you sure? Even with just $n=2$, this has mod 1, so it like's we have to take so many cases at least if we're going to prove this by computing the joint distribution, which is hopefully joint uniform, AFTER already showing they are individually uniform. Sounds long even if simple.

Comment: 5 - Wait this doesn’t quite answer the question at the end, i think (even though of course you're answering the problem of finding the pdf). i'm asking how to make the argument precise, not for any particular method of finding the pdf of E. where's the '2', and where's the '1-e'? it seems your way is cdf and then pdf. i'm wondering if there's some way to go straight to the pdf. like $P(E=e) = P(A \in (e,1)) + P(C \in (e,1))$ or something. like there are (3-1)!=2!=2 circular permutations of the 3 iid uniform(0,1) objects (A,B,C) and then for each of the permutations we have $P(A \in (e,1))=1-e$

Comment: I suppose that "simple to show that" is relative to the training of the person doing the showing.  The simplest way to show this would be to use the law of total probability, conditioning on $X_0 = x_0$ so that the modular rotation is relative to a fixed point.  You're right that you'd show the joint distribution to be IID uniform.  I haven't done this personally, but I doubt it is particularly onerous.  In any case, the intuition of the result is pretty clear.

Comment: There are probably all sorts of other ways you could prove this, but note that if you are using probabilities of values falling within sets, then that is very similar to going by way of the CDF.